# Adding a Space when using addClass and variables using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery read some text then add a class based on the value of this text. (The text read is rendered by my CMS).

The HTML Looks like this:

```
<ul class="zoneSubscriptions">
 <li>
   <ul>
      <li class="zoneName"><a href="#">Professional</a></li>
      <li>Never</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
   <ul>
     <li class="zoneName"><a href="#">RTTM</a></li>
     <li>Never</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to read the text of `class="zoneName"`and add a class based on this.

JS to do this:

```
$(function() {
   var zone = $( ".zoneName" ).text();
   $( "#zones" ).addClass( zone );
});
```

This works without issue, however, I need it to add two classes, `Professional` and `RTTM`. What it adds is `ProfessionalRTTM`.

My question is how would I add the classes while keeping a space between the words?

In other words it should render like this: `class="Professional RTTM"` *not* `class="ProfessionalRTTM"`

Note: In my example there are two "zoneName"s. There could be anywhere from 1 to 5 or more when used live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try iterating the tags:

```
var $zones = $("#zones");

$(".zoneName").each(function () {
  $zones.addClass( $(this).text() );
});
```

Also possible (if you want to reuse the list of class names)

```
var classes = [];
$(".zoneName").each(function () {
  classes.push($(this).text());
});

$("#zones").addClass(classes.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `.text()` on multiple results which is joining them together.

Why not do something like this instead:

```
var zone = $( ".zoneName" ).each(function(){
    $("#zones").addClass($(this).text());
});
```

Find all your `.zoneName`s and then call `addClass` for each one.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VXC5J/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate across the `.zoneName`s, otherwise your `.text()` will be a one undivided string (unless you have whitespace in there)

```
$(".zoneName").each(function() { 
    $("#zones").addClass($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback function of `addClass()`, and use `map()` to get an array of the text, then simply join with a space:

```
$('#zones').addClass(function() {
    return $('.zoneName').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(' ');
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dha9v/2/)